# Is E.M Luks algorithm for trivalent graph isomorphism parallelizable?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, graph-isomorphism

> It is still open whether also Luks’ efficient GI algorithm for graphs with bounded degree is parallelizable  i.e. [NC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)).

I get this from the survey "On Graph Isomorphism for Restricted Graph Classes" by Johannes Köbler   [(see this)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0e82/4ec8f63c2d5a1dae2df54d3689e3573ee881.pdf)

**My question :** Luks has given an algorithm for trivalent GI (degree at most three ) [(see section 2)](http://vlsicad.eecs.umich.edu/BK/SAUCY/papers/iso.pdf). Is that algorithm also not parallelizable ? If yes provide the reference.